# Saltar duplicados en inserción SQL

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql, trigger

desde hace días me vengo quebrando la cabeza con este problema, tengo el siguiente script en sql que sirve para hacer una exportación diaria de los datos de facturación a una tabla custom que yo mismo hice...

```
INSERT INTO T_FACTURACLI (IDFactura, FechaDocumento, NombreCliente, NIT, DireccionFacturacion, Folio, Subfolio, Habitacion, Serie, NumeroDoc, IdVendedor, IDClienteIQware, IDClienteSAP, DocType)
SELECT        oaccPrintInvoice.ID_Invoice AS IDFactura, oaccPrintInvoice.IssueDate AS FechaDocumento, oaccPrintInvoice.AccountName AS NombreCliente, oaccPrintInvoice.TaxID1 AS NIT,
                         oaccPrintInvoice.ClientAddress AS DireccionFacturacion, oaccPrintInvoice.AccountNo AS Folio, CASE SubFolio WHEN 0 THEN 'A' WHEN 1 THEN 'B' WHEN 2 THEN 'C' WHEN 3 THEN 'D' END AS Subfolio,
                         rmRoom.RoomNo AS Habitacion, oaccPrintInvoice.SerialNo AS Serie, oaccPrintInvoice.InvoiceNumber AS NumeroDoc, V_Guest.ID_SrcBusiness AS IDVendor, V_Guest.ID_Guest AS IDClienteIQware,
                         obooGuest.PersonalOccupation AS IDClienteSAP, oaccPrintInvoice.DocType
FROM            oaccPrintInvoice INNER JOIN
                         V_Guest ON oaccPrintInvoice.ID_Account = V_Guest.ID_Account INNER JOIN
                         rmRoom ON V_Guest.ID_Room = rmRoom.ID_Room INNER JOIN
                         obooGuest ON V_Guest.ID_Guest = obooGuest.ID_Guest
WHERE        (oaccPrintInvoice.IssueDate = (SELECT CurrentHotelDate - 1 FROM prProperty)) AND (oaccPrintInvoice.SerialNo IS NOT NULL)
```

Esta es una muestra de los datos a exportar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por un problema de lógica en el sistema están habiendo muchos registros duplicados, en lo que la empresa encargada de hacer el desarrollo hace los cambios para corregir el problema necesito seguir haciendo estas exportaciones. Lo que yo necesito en concreto es validar que no hayan registros duplicados validando tres datos de esta exportación (Serie, NumeroDoc y DocType).

Hay alguna forma de poder continuar con el proceso de exportación saltando los registros duplicados? He leído algo acerca de hacerlo mediante Triggers pero no tengo muy claro cómo hacerlo, de ante mano muchas gracias.

Dejo los scripts que estoy utilizando para validar esta información y captura de sus resultados:

```
--VALIDACION DE INTEGRA (SERIE, DOCUMENTO, TIPO)
SELECT SerialNo, InvoiceNumber, DocType, count(*)
FROM oaccPrintInvoice
GROUP BY SerialNo, InvoiceNumber, DocType
HAVING count(*) > 1

--VER DETALLE DE LOS REGISTROS DUPLICADOS
SELECT * FROM oaccPrintInvoice
WHERE SerialNo = 'B2' AND InvoiceNumber = 2736
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me surge una duda. Si consideras estos dos registros duplicados pero tienes campos que no lo están, ¿cuál de los dos valores vas a insertar? Por ejemplo, en el caso de `ID_Invoice`, ¿qué `IDFactura` vas a insertar en `T_FACTURACLI`?

Comment: El primer correlativo en ID_Invoice es el criterio por el momento, esto como repito hasta que el fabricante del sistema realice los cambios para corregir estas carencias

Answer (score 1):

Al final para dejar documentada una solución a mi problema les comento que encontré que se puede agregar la función IGNORE_DUP_KEY al script para la creación de la tabla por lo que mi tabla queda de la siguiente manera:

```
USE [SantoDomingoPMS]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[T_FACTURACLI]    Script Date: 5/19/2018 9:26:56 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_FACTURACLI](
    [IDFactura] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FechaCreacion] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [FechaDocumento] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [NombreCliente] [nvarchar](62) NOT NULL,
    [NIT] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [DireccionFacturacion] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Folio] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Subfolio] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [Habitacion] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Serie] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [NumeroDoc] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [IdVendedor] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [IDClienteIQware] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDClienteSAP] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DocType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Enviar] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Pagar] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SapDocEntry] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_t_facturacli] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDFactura] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [uk_t_facturacli] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Serie] ASC,
    [NumeroDoc] ASC,
    [DocType] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_FACTURACLI] ADD  CONSTRAINT [df_facturacli_fechaCreacion]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [FechaCreacion]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_FACTURACLI] ADD  CONSTRAINT [df_facturacli_enviar]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Enviar]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_FACTURACLI] ADD  CONSTRAINT [df_facturacli_pagar]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Pagar]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_FACTURACLI]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [chk_doctype] CHECK  (([DocType]=(0) OR [DocType]=(1)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_FACTURACLI] CHECK CONSTRAINT [chk_doctype]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_FACTURACLI]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [chk_facturacli_subfolio] CHECK  (([Subfolio]='A' OR [Subfolio]='B' OR [Subfolio]='C' OR [Subfolio]='D'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_FACTURACLI] CHECK CONSTRAINT [chk_facturacli_subfolio]
GO
```

Active la función IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON en mi CONSTRAINT para que ignore los registros duplicados y no de error en la inserción, muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

**Editado a partir de aclaración en comentarios:**

A mi modo de ver, podría solucionarse con un `NOT EXISTS`. Insertamos siempre que en `T_FATURACLI` no exista la clave `serie-numerodoc-doctype` que se va a insertar.

```
INSERT INTO T_FACTURACLI (IDFactura, FechaDocumento, NombreCliente, NIT, DireccionFacturacion, Folio, Subfolio, Habitacion, Serie, NumeroDoc, IdVendedor, IDClienteIQware, IDClienteSAP, DocType)
SELECT DISTINCT oaccPrintInvoice.ID_Invoice AS IDFactura, oaccPrintInvoice.IssueDate AS FechaDocumento, oaccPrintInvoice.AccountName AS NombreCliente, oaccPrintInvoice.TaxID1 AS NIT,
                         oaccPrintInvoice.ClientAddress AS DireccionFacturacion, oaccPrintInvoice.AccountNo AS Folio, CASE SubFolio WHEN 0 THEN 'A' WHEN 1 THEN 'B' WHEN 2 THEN 'C' WHEN 3 THEN 'D' END AS Subfolio,
                         rmRoom.RoomNo AS Habitacion, oaccPrintInvoice.SerialNo AS Serie, oaccPrintInvoice.InvoiceNumber AS NumeroDoc, V_Guest.ID_SrcBusiness AS IDVendor, V_Guest.ID_Guest AS IDClienteIQware,
                         obooGuest.PersonalOccupation AS IDClienteSAP, oaccPrintInvoice.DocType
FROM            oaccPrintInvoice INNER JOIN
                         V_Guest ON oaccPrintInvoice.ID_Account = V_Guest.ID_Account INNER JOIN
                         rmRoom ON V_Guest.ID_Room = rmRoom.ID_Room INNER JOIN
                         obooGuest ON V_Guest.ID_Guest = obooGuest.ID_Guest
WHERE        (oaccPrintInvoice.IssueDate = (SELECT CurrentHotelDate - 1 FROM prProperty)) AND (oaccPrintInvoice.SerialNo IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Fijate que esta modificación no me da error de sintaxis pero no me valida la información sigue queriendo exportar esos duplicados en SerialNo, InvoiceNumber y DocType

Comment: Una pregunta; cuando hablas de registros duplicados, ¿te refieres a registros que ya existen en `T_FACTURASCLI` o están duplicados en el `SELECT`?

Comment: Me refiero a que son registros que ya se encuentran duplicados en las tablas de origen y que necesito descartar para insertar solo 1 de ellos en T_FACTURASCLI

Comment: En este caso, ¿no te valdría con un `DISTINCT`? He editado la respuesta.

Comment: Esa fue la primera opción que intenté, lo probé únicamente en la consulta sin inserción  y me devuelve la misma cantidad de registro, por supuesto entonces también vienen los registros duplciados

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y mostrar 2 de esos registros duplicados completos?

Comment: Ya he editado mi pregunta, muchas gracias